# To prove uniqueness of Rotation Tensor

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics, tensor-calculus

How can you prove that a rotation tensor which rotates some given vector is a unique tensor?

Let's say we have a vector 'a' and we take a tensor product of that vector with some tensor 'Z' such that:

Z.a=b

where 'b' is a rotated version of the vector 'a'. So I want help to prove that the tensor 'Z' is a unique tensor. In other words, if another tensor, say 'Y', exists such that

Y.a=b

then we have to prove that Y must be equal to Z.

For my definition of a 'rotation tensor', you can refer to the 12th page of the pdf whose link is: http://www.mech.utah.edu/~brannon/public/rotation.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: I have updated it now. Let me know if I need to expatiate further.

Comment: Okay, nice; but it would be better to post the relevant texts & definition from the link you gave in the question. You can't expect every one to go to your link  to get the necessary info.

Comment: Okay. Can you tell me how to write equations here?

Comment: There is guideline on how to use $\LaTeX$ here; however, I'm willing to modify those if you can't; but write it first; I'll modify them. You can also check this quick reference on mathjax at Maths SE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for your math question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is false (in $\mathbb R^3$).

If $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are fixed vectors (I assume they are not co-linear and satisfy $|\vec{a}|=|\vec{b}| \neq 0$) there are **infinitely many** rotations $R \in O(3)$ such that $R\vec{a}=\vec{b}$.

One is the rotation $R$ of the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ performed around an axis orthogonal to the plane determined by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. However if $R'$ is a rotation around $\vec{a}$ of an arbitrary angle, $RR' \vec{a} = R\vec{a} = \vec{b}$ and $RR' \neq R$.

Comment: Oh that was a brilliant exposition, sir. Thank you very much :-)